# how to parse a word doc using Tikaparser and save content in an XML or JSON

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

I am parsing a word file using below code in Java

```
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
InputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(new ToXMLContentHandler());             
parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
```

How to generate an xml/JSON to save the content please?

Comment: Follow the [Parsing to XML example on the Tika website](http://tika.apache.org/1.14/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML) and be done?

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr, but I am able to fetch content from word document(Not in desired format though) while parsing using ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();
But I am parsing using ContentHandler handler = new MatchingContentHandler(new ToXMLContentHandler(), divContentMatcher); I am not able to fetch anything, I am still stuck with how to I get content in required format

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the content of doc using handler and metadata information as below. Set These information in JSON or generate XML as per your requirement.

```
System.out.println("Contents of the document:" + handler.toString());
System.out.println(" " + metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE));
System.out.println("Sample Word Document"+ metadata.get(TikaCoreProperties.TITLE));
System.out.println("Metadata of the document:");
String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

for(String name : metadataNames) {
     System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhilash, but I am not interested in fetching Metadata of document(a resume), rather I want to parse the document (say 4 pages) into a json document which has say structure like
resume 
{
   resumeMetadata:{name:abc.docx, something1:value1, resumeLocationURL:url .....},
   page1:{ page1Table: tableData, page1Para1: paragraphData1, page1Techwords:page1TechValues, page1FullContent:  page1FullText, page1somethingelse:},
page2:{...},
page3{....},
page4{....}
}